# iTunesconnect, App Review Contact Information

Tags: ios6, app-store-connect

I'm having trouble (again) with itunes connect.

I want to add a new version for my app, but I have the message

```
The following error(s) occurred:

You must provide all required contact information. To edit your contact details, click Edit in the App Review section.
```

But, I can't find where should I add the information! where is it?

Comment: Have you tried asking Apple about the Apple services?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Did you scroll down?

The information is the bottom of the page where you see the error on top (see screenshot).

Press the edit button next to App Review Information to edit it.

You can find more information on this topic here:

- [Apple's Guide For Editing and Updating App Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW1)

it contains a subsection for the:

- [App Review Information](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnect_Guide/11_EditingandUpdatingAppInformation/EditingandUpdatingAppInformation.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011225-CH14-SW12)

[image]